# iOS - Facebook Share - French Url converted to English

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiactivityviewcontroller, facebook-share

I'm working on social share application for two languages, french and english. When I share the french URL something like this "https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app", the share popup shows the correct url but in my timeline if I clicks that like it goes to english version, this one "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app". I've used `UIActivityViewController`for sharing.

I don't know it may be Facebook limitation or something caused on this.

Please advise me how to share the url as it is.